# How to render common VIEW (HTML and JavaScript) across different projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Our project has different user interfaces (VIEWS) as separate projects. Example project A will render VIEW_A and project B will render VIEW_B. But both these projects have a common Header View (e.g. VIEW_HEADER) that contains Project Logo and other common stuff. Now if I want to render this common VIEW_HEADER in both the projects/views A and B, how do I do it. Right now I'm using embedded views. In a separate project I create the common header view, make a DLL of it and include that in projects A and B.

Is there any other elegant solution ? I may sound stupid but I m new to MVC, please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Right now I'm using embedded views. In a separate project I create the common header view, make a DLL of it and include that in projects A and B.

**If you use [Razor Generator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) you have chosen one of the best solutions already. Otherwise you have to try it.**

It is simple and powerful. 
In order to start using it you should

1. install [Razor Generator extension into your Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1f6ec6ff-e89b-4c47-8e79-d2d68df894ec/). This plugin is needed to generate c# files from razor views. In order to force generation custom tool should be chosen.
   [image]
2. add [RazorGenerator.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.Mvc) to library project (During package installation will be added `RazorGeneratorMvcStart` static class that registers `PrecompiledMvcEngine`).

   ```
   public static class RazorGeneratorMvcStart {
       public static void Start() {
           var engine = new PrecompiledMvcEngine(typeof(RazorGeneratorMvcStart).Assembly) {
               UsePhysicalViewsIfNewer = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal
           };

           ViewEngines.Engines.Insert(0, engine);

           // StartPage lookups are done by WebPages. 
           VirtualPathFactoryManager.RegisterVirtualPathFactory(engine);
       }
   }
   ```
3. add reference to your library project from any MVC application in order to use precompiled view.